# Extracting date value from the XML string

Tags: java

I am having string in the below format and I want extract date value for the same. Can anyone help me to do the same.

```
String xmsl ="<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-16\\\"?>\\n<MATDT xmlns=\\\"http://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSTDService\\\">2018-10-06</MATDT>\n";
```

Comment: Parse the xml using a proper xml parser and if needed parse the date with a date parser as well (e.g. `SimpleDateFormat`).

Answer (score 0):

If your string is constant and only date value is changing, then you can simply do this by `substring(beginIndex, endIndex)`

```
String xmsl ="\nhttp://fcubs.ofss.com/service/FCUBSTDService\\\">2018-10-06\n";
String dateExact = xmsl.substring(xmsl.indexOf(">")+1, xmsl.lastIndexOf("\n"));
System.out.println(dateExact);
```